# fit a generalized model in R

Tags: r, model

Given the data:

```
1957 1497
1958 1518
1959 1541
1960 1565
1961 1592
1962 1620
1963 1651
1964 1684
1965 1718
1966 1753
1967 1790
1968 1828
1969 1868
1970 1910
1971 1953
1972 1996
1973 2036
1974 2072
1975 2103
1976 2131
1977 2156
1978 2180
1979 2201
1980 2221
1981 2237
1982 2250
1983 2260
1984 2268
1985 2275
1986 2280
```

Where the first column are years and the second one are houses.

```
data<-read.table('/data.dat' , header=F)
names(data) <-c ('years','houses')
attach(data)
summary(data)
plot(data)
```

I can't figure out how to make a proper model in R, because of there are only one variable for the function. My question comes now: How can I fit a proper model for this dataset in R?

Comment: Fit a proper model for... what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can start by reading `?lm`, `?glm`, `?loglin` and `?loglm` .

Comment: Honestly you could do this with a piece of graphing paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters state, you need to specify more about your problem to get a unique answer.  But to get you started, here is a basic linear model in R, assuming that you are trying to use `years` to predict `houses`:

```
mod = lm(houses~years, data = data)
summary(mod)
```